# How to access current plain-object I'm iterating over an arrays of in Meteor template

Tags: arrays, meteor, handlebars.js

I have an array of plain-objects (returned by a helper, but it's irrelevant to the question):

```
Things = [{
  a: 'some thing'
}, {
  a: 'more thing'
}];
```

I then iterate over it in a Meteor template:

```
{{#each Things}}
  <button>{{a}}</button>
{{/each}}
```

In case of collections, it's a super handy shortcut to the context from an event:

```
Template.whatever.events({
  'click button': () => console.log(this); // e.g., {a: 'some thing'}
});
```

But in case of a plain-object, the `this` shortcut doesn't work, it references to `window` object.

How can I extract the array item that's the context of `each` block from within the even handler without explicitly adding some unique identifiers to iterables?

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the `arrow` es15 syntax you are using.  Arrow syntax preserves the context of `this` in a function.  I am not sure why it would work for a collection and not an array of objects, but if you use `function` notation instead it will work.

```
Template.whatever.events({
  'click button': function () {
       console.log(this);  // e.g., {a: 'some thing'}
  }
});
```